# Collect multiple RDD with a list of column values - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a RDD and a list of values. How can I filter them based on the list of values and collect them as separate RDD?

For example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((4, "blah", 2), (2, "", 3), (56, "foo", 3), (100, null, 5)))
```

How can I pass a list of values to collect all the filtered RDD in a list? For example, for the list:

```
val l = List(2,3)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most situations, it's easier to work with a single dataframe instead of a list of dataframes. To filter a dataframe with a list of values, use `isin` as in the answer by Gaurang Shah.

However, if you really want a list of dataframes that is possible as well. Simply `map` over the list and filter the dataframe in each step as follows:

```
val dfs = l.map(x => df.filter($"C" === x))
```

`dfs` here will be a `List[DataFrame]` as wanted.

---

**For RDDs:**

If you work with a `RDD`, the only thing to change is the filter operation:

```
val rdds = l.map(x => rdd.filter(c => c._3 === x))
```

`rdds` will be a `List[RDD]`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question now. +1 for your answer. Your solution looks correct for a DataFrame. How can achieve the same in a RDD?

Comment: @mani_nz: I added a section for that. Normally dataframes is prefered for newer spark versions but in this case the command in very similar.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the method `isin` if you have DataFrame (as per your question before modification)

```
scala> df.filter($"C" isin (2,3)).show()
+---+----+---+
|  A|   B|  C|
+---+----+---+
|  4|blah|  2|
|  2|    |  3|
| 56| foo|  3|
+---+----+---+
```

**For RDD**: yes there are reason you would use RDD, however if you are using `Spark 2.x` those reason are very limited.

RDD are low-level API. And you code will look like this.

```
scala> val rdd1 = rdd.filter(c=>List(2,3).contains(c._3))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at <console>:25

scala> rdd1.collect().foreach(println)
(4,blah,2)
(2,,3)
(56,foo,3)
```

Comment: No this way I will get one RDD. I want two RDD from that list. Number of items in list should the total number of RDD I have want

Comment: @mani_nz do you want `RDD` or `DataFrame`, both are different. You will be good with `DF` only. what is the purpose of creating multiple dataframe?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the question again. I have an RDD and want to filter RDD based on the values in the RDD with a list separately per input in the list.

Comment: @mani_nz I have updated the answer. However for your next question if you get in a situation where whole content of your question getting changed, I would suggest to open a new question.

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to use the column name 'C' instead of _3 in contains()?

Comment: ah I see.. I have a JSON instead of a Seq. hence my question. Accepting it as it answers the asked question.Cheers!